# EntityFramework - Saving Aggregates Roots Which Contain Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, ddd-repositories

I'm using the Entity Framework for my C# application.

I am close to implementing it fully, but am a little confused by the fluent API.

## An Overview of my classes (simplified)

```
class Customer : IEntity {
    public Id { get; set; }
    public Name Name { get; set; };

    public Customer() {}

    public Customer( Name name ){
        this.name = name;
    }
}


class Name {
    public String Title;
    public String Forename;
    public String Surname;

    public Name(){}

    public Name( String Title, String Forename, String Surname ){
        // assign values
    }
}
```

The save, with entity framework, seems to work fine; there aren't any exceptions, at least.
However, when I try to get all customers using `DbContext.getAll()`, it throws a  NullReferenceException when trying to print `customer.Name.Forename` to the output window. I can see that `customer.Name` is null - this is obviously what's causing that exception.

Why is Name (along with all other similar properties) null? How do I resolve this?

Note:
I have a date in the Customer model and this is populating correctly after I added the following to my DbContext implementation...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
}
```

I'm thinking I need to add something here to be able to map the Name correctly. I'm just not sure on how to go about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How soon after pulling your entity are you trying to access `customer.Name.Forename`? If it's outside the scope of your DbContext, you will experience this issue if you are using lazy loading.

Comment: I have disabled lazy loading in the constructor of my DbContext with `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`, so this can't be the problem. There customer is there, otherwise it wouldn't do any iterations. Also, the date field I have in the model is populated

Comment: This has nothing to do with DDD or aggregates and entities. You  want to load child entities together with a root class. *Have* you mapped the relation between the classes? Your mapping only shows an unrelated property type specification. Also, instead of disabling lazy loading, use the `Include()` method.

Comment: Title, Forename and Surname should be in your Customer Table in the database? Consider putting them in your customer class directly or make a complex type for Name if you look to reuse it elsewhere

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I understand that, technically this has nothing to do with DDD (otherwise there would be coupling that I need to sort). I have asked the question using this example to better highlight my situation.

Comment: @HansVG - I am reusing `Name` in other aggregates. I have added a `[ComplexType]` annotation to the `Name` class and it looks to be working now. I'll update my question

Comment: @Josh-Mason it had the opposite effect - it confused things.  `Name` is either a Complex type or an Entity. In either case, the mapping is missing. You don't need to disable lazy loading, that's like throwing the baby with the bathwater. Just use the `Include` method. What would help would be the query code. Did you use `Include()`? Where did you try to access the property ?

Comment: `Name` is a ComplexType as the values will be different for each `Customer`, having mappings would surely just slow things down when loading and saving.
I'm not really sure how or where to use `Include()`. Could you point me to some documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I have added `[ComplexType]` above the `Name` class and it is working now.

For clarity:

```
[ComplexType]
class Name {
    ...
}
```